# How to ignore function in onclick based on certain condition

Tags: jquery

Why is the input onclick function called first before going to the jquery onclick function.

When text is 1, Hello World alert is displayed (myFunc) then my second alert (("#btn").on('click') is displayed. How to make it read the ("#btn").on('click' before myFunc?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type=text id="txt">
<input type=button value="click" onclick="myFunc()" id="btn">

</body>

<script>
$("#btn").on('click', function(e){
  if($("#txt").val() == "1"){
    alert("do not show Hello World alert");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function myFunc() {
    alert("Hello World!!!");
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `false` your `clickHandler`

```
var btn = $("#btn");
var clickHandler = btn[0].onclick;
btn[0].onclick = false;


$("#btn").click(function(event) {
  if($("#txt").val() == "1"){
    alert("do not show Hello World alert");
  }
});

function myFunc() {
  alert("Hello World!!!");
}
```

If you want to call `myFunc()` again, then you have to call like this:

`clickhandler.call(this, event);`

Comment: thank you! i've been using the wrong approach. i was using $(this).click(clickhandler); but it works when i changed it to clickhandler.call(this, event);

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:
You have 2 event handlers for your button. 
The first is `onclick="myFunc()"`. And the second is your `jQuery` registration `$("#btn").on('click', ...`

Just remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove your onclick function using `attr` and `removeAttr` functions. or remove one of handler method.

HTML code:

```
<input type=text id="txt">
<input type=button value="click" id="btn">
```

JS code:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function(e){
  if($("#txt").val() == "1"){
    //$("#btn").attr("onclick","myFunc()");
    alert("do not show Hello World alert");
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunc();
  }
});

function myFunc() {
    alert("Hello World!!!");
    //$("#btn").removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply condition to myFunc() and avoid $("#btn").on('click', function(e){})

```
function myFunc() {
  if($("#txt").val() == "1"){
      alert("do not show Hello World alert");
  }else{
    alert("Hello World!!!");
  }
}
```